# Ruby: Doing binary operations on bitstrings

Tags: ruby, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have an array of long(45) character bitstrings, that basically represent the boolean state of a bunch of attributes. I need to perform OR and AND operations on these strings and get back the resulting binary string. 
ex:

```
    a = "100"
    b = "101"
```

I now need to compute:

```
    a_or_b  = "101"
    a_and_b = "100"
```

Is there efficient anyway for me to do this? Can I use the bitwise operators somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `Integer#to_s(base)` and `String.to_i(base)` available to you.

`a_and_b = (a.to_i(2) & b.to_i(2)).to_s(2)`

`a_or_b  = (a.to_i(2) | b.to_i(2)).to_s(2)`

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I am a bit of a noob in this area, so forgive me if this is stupid. But will this be faster than looping? Are the to binary and back to string operations  expensive?

Comment: I do not think loop would be faster. As the Ruby basic apis are implemented in C, which should be faster than Ruby code itself.

Comment: Great, thank you. I did some quick benchmarking and the results were stunning. For 50,000 iters, the binary operations took 0.11 secs and the same thing with a ruby loop took 2.71 seconds.